# Reducing DB calls when using RABL with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongoid, rabl, object-object-mapping

I have a few scenarios where I would like to do as little DB calls as much as possible via eager loading, but I have not been able to do it well.

Given the 2 scenarios below, how can i change my RABL to do as little calls as possible?

---

OBJECT MODEL:

```
Posts 
-> belongs_to user
-> has_many: Comments 
     -> Comment belongs_to user
-> has_many: Tags
     -> Tag belongs_to user
```

RABL (Both of these will cause the DB to do many individual calls)

```
node(:comments) do |p|
  p.filtered_comments(@user)
end

child :tags do
  attribute :text
  child :users do
     attribute :nickname
  end
end
```

CONTROLLER QUERY

```
Post.includes(user, comments, tags)...
```

POST.RB

```
def filtered_comments
    comments = self.comments.where(:blocked=>false).all
    json = Rabl::Renderer.json(comments, 'comments/list', view_path: 'app/views')
    JSON.parse(json).map do |c|
      c['comment']
    end
end
```

Comment: do u have any logs on how many queries are happening?

Comment: How do you pass the user to `filtered_comments` method if it does not accepts any?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the controller defines the object that rabl iterates across, say a `@user`.

So in the controller, I normally eager-load relations, such as permissions and articles like so: `@user = User.find(1).includes(:permissions, :articles)`, and respons with said user object like this: `respond_with @user`.

Then, in the rabl file, I have something like:

```
# some_file.json.rabl
object @user
child :permissions do
  attributes :name
end
node :first_article do |u|
  u.articles.first
end
```

This fixed my version of the chatty view files.